# CSS: Image scale with width

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, background-image

I have a div with an [image background](https://unsplash.com/photos/063pYxHJwq0) (in React with Next.js, but that shouldn't matter).

```js
import styles from './my-component.module.css';
import Background from '../../../public/assets/images/background-image.png';

// later

<div
  style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${Background})` }}
  className={`${styles['background-image']}`}
>
```

Here is the CSS I'm currently using:

```css
.background-image {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: auto;
}
```

I can't get the image to take the full height. It should always take the display's width, but take as much height as it can without stretching or repeating. How can I do that?

[image]

**Update:** Yes, the container has more height than the element.

[image]

**Update 2** Viira's solution almost works, but the image doesn't respect padding on the right side.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it is taking up the full height of it's container to me, are you sure your container element isn't just smaller than you expected?

Comment: can you attach a fiddle ?

Comment: @DBS yes! (I updated the question accordingly)

Comment: maybe don't use it as background and just set an img

Comment: your container that's containing the image probably has a height property set. Otherwise in `.background-image`. Instead of auto, set it to the actual height of the image. (bare scaling in mind).

Comment: @Joel But that's exactly the problem. The height should vary, depending on the window width.

Comment: If you do not set a height to div (100%, / 100vh ...), the image will simply be adjusted to the height of the **parent**.                                                           
Then you have two options:
1- Use the `img` tag.
2- Give a specific height to the parent div.

Comment: do you want to display the image to full height?

Comment: @Viira Excatly! Sorry, still trying to reproduce the issue in a fiddle ...

Comment: You are inspecting the parent element though, rather than the element you have applied the background to. The code is working correctly, the image covers the element it is a background for. If you want to cover the parent, you need to play around with flex or other methods to get the child element to fill

Comment: No worries I have figured it out.

Comment: @SamWillis Sorry, maybe me question was unclear. I want the `div` to stretch as far as it can, until the image has its full width. Meaning it should take as much width as in my screenshot, but maintain the aspect ratio.

Comment: I have posted my answer please check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help.

Don't set it in background image try insert it in img tag

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.background-image {
  
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.img {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
 
.img img {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-water-drop-on-dandelion-260nw-789676552.jpg">
      </div>
    <div class="text">
  <h1>Are you ready</h1>
  <p>Click the link</p>
  <button>Click Here</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

NOTE:  The image is stretched to full width because its resolution is low. you can set it's width to auto to display its original size.

Solution 2:

As the OP mentioned, padding is not respected by the image. I came up with a solution. Since the .container div is in display: table; padding isn't allowed there. So, by giving the padding to its parent .background-image this issue will be lifted.

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.background-image {
  
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 15px 40px;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.img {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
 
.img img {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-water-drop-on-dandelion-260nw-789676552.jpg">
      </div>
    <div class="text">
  <h1>Are you ready</h1>
  <p>Click the link</p>
  <button>Click Here</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Set padding for .background-image div so that the padding will apply.

Comment: Thank you so much! You already helped a lot. This solution almost works, but it doesn't respect padding of parent components. I ammended the question.

Comment: @J.Hesters I have updated my answer please check it

Answer (score 0):

So you want your image to determine the height of your div. That is not possible when using the image as background.

You need to load image into dom as an element which can then be used to determine the height of your div, if you want to show some content on top of the image in this case, you will have to overlay it on top of the image.

Here's a sample html structure you can use to achieve this

```html
<div style="position:relative">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1573496528816-a104a722b3db?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" style="width:100%; height: auto;" />
  <div style="position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%">
    // YOUR CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good explanation, AvcS

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ended up solving it:

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

import styles from './background-image-card.module.css';

function BackgroundImageCard({ alt, children, className, image }) {
  return (
    <div className={`${className} ${styles.container}`}>
      <div className={styles.overlay} />
      <img alt={alt} src={image} className={styles['background-image']} />
      <div className={styles.content}>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

BackgroundImageCard.propTypes = {
  alt: PropTypes.string,
  children: PropTypes.node,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  image: PropTypes.string,
};

export default BackgroundImageCard;
```

```css
.container {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
    background: var(--gray-800);
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.background-image {
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
}
```